# session in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, express-session

I' m using `const SessionStore = require('express-session-sequelize')(expressSession.Store);` for storing the sessions.
I would like to save in session currenty user, which log to site.

here is a configuration for store:

```
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const SessionStore = require('express-session-sequelize')(expressSession.Store);
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const myDatabase = new Sequelize('analytic', 'root', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

const sequelizeSessionStore = new SessionStore({
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // The interval at which to cleanup expired sessions in milliseconds.
    expiration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // The maximum age (in milliseconds) of a valid session.
    db: myDatabase
});
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: '412415415415415121212121',
    store: sequelizeSessionStore,
    name: 'session_id',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

So, now for login I have this:

```
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../../model').User;
var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app = require("../../application");
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    User.doLogin(req).then((result)=> {
        if (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                if (result.error.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
                    res.send(400, { success: false, message: "Incorrect user / password"});
                } else if (result.error.hasOwnProperty("activated")) {
                    res.send(400, {success: false, message: "You are not activated yet"});
                }
            } else {
                //app.createSession(req);
                req.session.user = result;
                res.send(200, result);


            }
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Now, after this    `req.session.user = result;` I have in db session table with current user data. 
Now,

1. How can I verify is this user authenticated?
2. and I notice that for every request I get diferrent sessionID (is this ok)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi there for user manager you can use [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/)
it's a great user manager for express and provide a high quality for handle with your user manager logic .